# Comprar Funcionalidade no App (In Billing)

Tags: java, android, android-billing

Gostaria de fazer com que no meu app tivesse a opção de comprar funcionalidade.

Tipo fiz dois apps, um pago (completo) e outro grátis (com propaganda).

Gostaria que ao a pessoa clicar para comprar retirasse a propaganda e adicionasse as activities referente ao pago.

Vi que tenho que fazer isso utilizando o In Billing, porém só achei para compra e listagem de produto:

```
List additionalSkuList = new ArrayList();
additionalSkuList.add(SKU_APPLE);
additionalSkuList.add(SKU_BANANA);
mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, additionalSkuList,
   mQueryFinishedListener);
```

E amostras de preço.

```
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener
   mQueryFinishedListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
   public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory)
   {
      if (result.isFailure()) {
         // handle error
         return;
       }

       String applePrice =
          inventory.getSkuDetails(SKU_APPLE).getPrice();
       String bananaPrice =
          inventory.getSkuDetails(SKU_BANANA).getPrice();

       // update the UI
   }
}
```

Gostaria de fazer com funcionalidade. Para:

- Retirar propaganda
- Adicionar tela

Alguém conhece um tutorial bacana que possa indicar?

Rerencia: [Establishing In-app Billing Products for Sale](https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/list-iab-products.html)

Comment: Tem algumas libraries que te dão uma mão pra desacoplar e resolver os problemas de integração com a API: https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3, https://github.com/serso/android-checkout, https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary

Comment: Estudando... Valeu